# how to link item in the list in excel cell to another list?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I created a list A of 10 items in a cell in spreadsheet. Now I need to create or map another list. That is if I select a single item in list A, List b must show the items corresponding to item in list A.Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to name some ranges on the lists you want to use for your validation.

In Sheet1 A1 to x1 list your options relating to List A and under each column "title" you place its corresponding new set op options. Then select each column and name it a range according to the option applicable.

Now in another column in Sheet2 A1 go to Data - Validation - List then source is 'Sheet1!$A$1:$x$1' extend this validation to as many cells as you want. In the next column you create another drop down list but this time in the source you need to enter "=INDIRECT($A1)" and extend this down as well.

you might be interested in [This article from Microsoft](http://blogs.office.com/2009/11/24/create-conditional-drop-down-lists/) which explains conditional drop down lists.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.